What is the explanation behind empty can test for supraspinatus tendon rupture?
Supraspinatus assists in abduction of the shoulder from 0-15°. The empty can test is done with shoulder at 90° abduction, when the deltoid already takes over and the patient is asked to resist a counter force to abduction. A positive test is seen if weakness or pain if felt. How does this make sense?

Hi, welcome to Medical Sciences. Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the reasons mentioned in this meta post, this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.
